# How to post-mortem debug .NET process and run powershell script as debugger action?

Tags: powershell, postmortem-debugging, debugdiag

Is there an easy way to monitor a given Windows process for a well defined .NET exception (either first or second chance) and run a powershell script when that exception is raised?  I don't really need a process dump (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET application errors are logged to the Application Events Log.
In the Scheduled Task manager, we can add a task which is triggered by a .NET Runtime exception event.

In practice, this is a bit troublesome to do by hand, since we need some additional `ValueQueries` to make this work, I've made a task XML which can be imported into the Task Scheduler. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/deviousasti/03c735687bb076a4f8e214073868958c).

The task needs to call our PowerShell script with an `EventId`, from which we retrieve the corresponding event log item, check the message for the stacktrace, and search for the matching known exception string.

```
param($eventRecordID, $eventChannel = "Application")

$event = Get-WinEvent -LogName $eventChannel -FilterXPath "<QueryList><Query Id='0' Path='$eventChannel'><Select Path='$eventChannel'>*[System[(EventRecordID=$eventRecordID)]]</Select></Query></QueryList>"

$stackTrace = $event.Message

if($stackTrace -match "ConfigurationErrorsException")
{
    echo "Error Thrown in Application"
    # do some stuff
}
```

Once the task is enabled, every time your .NET application faults, the PowerShell script should be run.